# How to access TWRequest.h

Tags: macos, twitter

I am following instructions written here, to compile a sample twitter client application. 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-twrequest

The problem that I have encountered is that TWRequest.h can not be found on my local machine. I am new to this environment. Would someone please guide me on where / how to add TWRequest.h to the environment / path?

Can I use apt-get / homebrew / mac-ports to get it? Is it residing on my machine but I can't find it? Or shall I download it manually and where from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TWRequest is contained within Twitter.framework, which is only available for iOS devices.

Comment: I am developing on a Mac Pro. However, I can not find the framework.

Comment: It's a part of the ***iOS*** SDK.  The headers are only available if you have a copy of the latest Xcode installed.  After that, just run a finder search for the UIKit.h header.